# Send email after 3 days of a date and if a cell is blank - Reference error -> Row not defined

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-developer-tools

I am trying to send an email based on this spreadsheet

[image: here]

My objective is to send an email after 4 days of the request date and if finish date is empty.

I have very little coding knowledge and I'm struggling to get through this as I get a reference error like this [image: error]

Can anyone help me out?

This is the code I'm using:

```
function offboardingReminderV2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // set active sheet to first sheet
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 2;
  // grab all data from user to days left
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow - startRow + 1, 8);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var users1 = [];
  var users2 = [];
  var users3 = [];

  // loop all data per row
  values.forEach(function(row) {
    // if days left is 4
    if(row[7] == 4) {
      // add user if 4 days left
      users1.push(row[3]);
      users2.push(row[4]);
      users3.push(row[5]);
    }
  });

  // if users has elements
  if (users3.length == '') {
  var message = "<html><body></h1><p><b>The following user(s) are 3 days due</font2></h1><p>https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d//edit#gid=3724</p>";
  var names = "<ul>";
  users2.forEach(function (user, i) {
    names += `<li>${user}, ${users1[i]}</li>`;
  });
  names += "</ul>"
  message = message + names + "</body></html>";
  var flexmails = "example@mail.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail(flexmails, "Reminder for Control", "", { htmlBody: message, noReply: true });
}
};
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Images should be used only when is not possible to add the same information as text.

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: According to your image you only have 7 columns of data so row[7] is undefined since arrays start their indexing at zero.  So probably all of the indexing in the loop is incorrect by one

Comment: In the future try adjusting the zoom on your spreadsheet when you take an image so that the image is more readable without having to click on it.  And use a program like Snagit to capture the image so that you can make it readable when it's posted.

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on so that this can be reproduced? I don't think it's not obvious, based on the code you shared, why you should get this error.

Comment: Thanks for the help Rúben,I have 8 columns, but as you said, it is not easy to read. I think I was getting the error from having another script open parallel to this one. Not sure. Anyways, it is solved now and I also incorporated @JamesVB answer

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code with your example data, but no error was thrown.  What line of code is throwing the error code?

Also, If you want to trigger an email when the "Finish Date" field is blank and greater than 3 days have passed, I think you need to change `if (users3.length == '') {` **to** `if (users2 == '') {` because **user2** stores the "Finish Date", and `users2.forEach(function (user, i) {` **to** `users1.forEach(function (user, i) {` because **user1** has the list of names.

Comment: Thanks James! You are right! There was no line in the eror. I think it came from having two scripts in opened in google apps script. As soon as I deleted one of them, it started running properly. Also used your code in order to get it to work :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my code, but still, I can't get it to work properly:

I don't get an error but when I run the code, I can't get it to send an email to all that have column 7 >= 4.

When I run the code with:

```
if(row[7] == 4)
```

-> // Can only get the 1st result with row 7 equal to 4 not all of those equal to 4

When I run the code with:

```
if(row[7] > 3)
```

-> // I can't get the email to be sent at all

This is the code i'm Using:

```
function PPRControl() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // set active sheet to first sheet
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheets()[0]);
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  // figure out what the last row is
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var startRow = 2;
  // grab all data from user to days left
  var range = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, lastRow - startRow + 1, 8);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var users1 = [];
  var users2 = [];
  var users3 = [];

  // loop all data per row
  values.forEach(function(row) {
    // if days left is 4
    if(row[7] == 4) {
      // add user if 4 days left
      users1.push(row[3]);
      users2.push(row[4]);
      users3.push(row[2]);
    }
  });

  // if users has elements
  if (users2 == '') {
  var message = "<html><body></h1><p><b>The following PPR(s) Control is due in 4 days</font2></h1><p>https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MtyKkB-Vihc/edit#gid=0</p>";
  var names = "<ul>";
  users1.forEach(function(user, i) {
    names += `<li>${users3} - ${users1[i]}</li>`;
  });
  names += "</ul>"
  message = message + names + "</body></html>";
  var flexmails = "mail@mail.com";
  MailApp.sendEmail(flexmails, "Reminder PPR Control", "", { htmlBody: message, noReply: true });
}
};
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what if you tried `if (row[7] !< 4)` ?  Also, I noticed that column 8 has numbers and text.  I wonder if the mixed types is causing you problems.